# MySQL table to Python list of lists using fetchall()

Tags: python, mysql

how can I transform this table:

```
ID        ITEM_CODE
--------------------
1            1AB
1            22S
1            1AB
2            67R
2            225
3            YYF
3            1AB
3            UUS
3            F67
3            F67
3            225
......
```

..to a list of lists, each list being a distinct ID containing its allocated item_codes?

in the form: `[[1AB,22S,1AB],[67R,225],[YYF,1AB,UUS,F67,F67,225]]`

Using this query:

```
SELECT ID, ITEM_CODE 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY ID;
```

and doing `cursor.fetchall()` in python does not return it as a list nor ordered by ID

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probly will have less post-processing in Python using that query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ITEM_CODE) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID 
ORDER BY ID;
```

That will directly produce that result:

```
1AB,22S,1AB
67R,225
YYF,1AB,UUS,F67,F67,225
```

After that, `cursor.fetchall()` will directly return more or less what you expected, I think.

---

EDIT:

```
result = [ split(row, ',') for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```